# Implementing isNil

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, lodash, truthiness

I am implementing a seemingly trivial utility function to check if a value is `null` or `undefined`.

My original implementation looked like this:

```
function isNil(value) {
  return value === null || value === undefined;
}
```

I then looked up [Lodash's implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isNil.js):

```
function isNil(value) {
  return value == null
}
```

On the surface, this would seem like a naiive approach since it violates eslint's [eqeqeq rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq) as well as only checking for `null`.

I'm guessing that this approach works due to a combination of JavaScript's [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) rules, but is there actually an advantage to Lodash's implementation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`value === null || value === undefined` and `value == null` are equivalent as can be seen in the specification of the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> The comparison `x == y`, where `x` and `y` are values, produces *true* or *false*. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> 2. If `x` is *null* and `y` is *undefined*, return *true*.
> 3. If `x` is *undefined* and `y` is *null*, return *true*.

The "eqeqeq" rule of ESLint is not relevent as it is just for linting, it does not enforce anything in ECMAScript itself. And lodash does not use that rule.

Technically, there is no real advantage as it has the exact same outcome. One might argue `value == null` could be faster as it does only do one equality check and does not perform up to two calls of the [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-strict-equality-comparison) like your first example. It does most probably not matter at all as even if there was a difference, it would be very small.

Personally, I would use the `value === null || value === undefined` as it is clearer and does not even need a documentation. Besides, tools like uglify could easily replace `value === null || value === undefined` with `value == null` for production.

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions seem to be functionally equivalent ([source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1399)).  Thus lodash's implementation would be preferable just because it requires slightly fewer comparisons.